# How does the linker handle identical template instantiations across translation units?

Tags: c++, templates, linker

Suppose I have two translation-units:

foo.cpp

```
void foo() {
  auto v = std::vector<int>();
}
```

bar.cpp

```
void bar() {
  auto v = std::vector<int>();
}
```

When I compile these translation-units, each will instantiate `std::vector<int>`.

My question is: how does this work at the linking stage?

- Do both instantiations have different mangled names?
- Does the linker remove them as duplicates?

Comment: The standard says you have a separate copy of the function in each translation unit. Some linkers, however, may provide an optimization that removes these duplicates.

Comment: I am not a compiler writer, and might be off but I am fairly certain build environments (compiler + linker) have become smart enough to remove the duplicates at link time. Code bloat involved with templates used to be a huge concern in the '90s but is not any longer.

Comment: *"Do both instantiations have different mangled names?"* why should they - they both are referring to the same type...

Comment: @W.F. I don't know how it works, that is why I am asking. If the compiler made the mangled names unique, then that would be one way to avoid collisions at linking.

Comment: Look up COMDAT sections.

Comment: @CodyGray the standard absolutely doesn't say anything remotely similar. A translation unit is a source file. A source file doesn't have any copies of template instantiations, it's a source, it only contains text.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

C++ *requires* that an [inline function definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)
be present in a translation unit that references the function. Template member
functions are implicitly inline, but also by default are instantiated with external
linkage. Hence the duplication of definitions that will be visible to the linker when
the same template is instantiated with the same template arguments in different
translation units. How the linker copes with this duplication is your question.

Your C++ compiler is subject to the C++ Standard, but your linker is not subject
to any codified standard as to how it shall link C++: it is a law unto itself,
rooted in computing history and indifferent to the source language of the object
code it links. Your compiler has to work with what a target linker
can and will do so that you can successfully link your programs and see them do
what you expect. So I'll show you how the GCC C++ compiler interworks with
the GNU linker to handle identical template instantiations in different translation units.

This demonstration exploits the fact that while the C++ Standard *requires* - 
by the [One Definition Rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)
- that the instantiations in different translation units of the same template with
the same template arguments shall have the same definition, the compiler - 
of course - cannot enforce any requirement like that on relationships between different
translation units. It has to trust us.

So we'll instantiate the same template with the same parameters in different
translation units, but we'll cheat by injecting a macro-controlled difference into
the implementations in different translation units that will subsequently show 
us which definition the linker picks.

If you suspect this cheat invalidates the demonstration, remember: the compiler 
cannot know whether the ODR is *ever* honoured across different translation units,
so it cannot behave differently on that account, and there's no such thing
as "cheating" the linker. Anyhow, the demo will demonstrate that it is valid.

First we have our cheat template header:

**thing.hpp**

```
#ifndef THING_HPP
#define THING_HPP
#ifndef ID
#error ID undefined
#endif

template<typename T>
struct thing
{
    T id() const {
        return T{ID};
    }
};

#endif
```

The value of the macro `ID` is the tracer value we can inject.

Next a source file:

**foo.cpp**

```
#define ID 0xf00
#include "thing.hpp"

unsigned foo()
{
    thing<unsigned> t;
    return t.id();
}
```

It defines function `foo`, in which `thing<unsigned>` is
instantiated to define `t`, and `t.id()` is returned. By being a function with 
external linkage that instantiates `thing<unsigned>`, `foo` serves the purposes 
of:-

- obliging the compiler to do that instantiating at all
- exposing the instantiation in linkage so we can then probe what the 
  linker does with it.

Another source file:

**boo.cpp**

```
#define ID 0xb00
#include "thing.hpp"

unsigned boo()
{
    thing<unsigned> t;
    return t.id();
}
```

which is just like `foo.cpp` except that it defines `boo` in place of `foo` and
sets `ID` = `0xb00`.

And lastly a program source:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern unsigned foo();
extern unsigned boo();

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex 
    << '\n' << foo()
    << '\n' << boo()
    << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This program will print, as hex, the return value of `foo()` - which our cheat should make
= `f00` - then the return value of `boo()` - which our cheat should make = `b00`.

Now we'll compile `foo.cpp`, and we'll do it with `-save-temps` because we want
a look at the assembly:

```
g++ -c -save-temps foo.cpp
```

This writes the assembly in `foo.s` and the portion of interest there is
the definition of `thing<unsigned int>::id() const` (mangled = `_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv`):

```
    .section    .text._ZNK5thingIjE2idEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
    .type   _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv, @function
_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $3840, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Three of the directives at the top are significant:

```
.section    .text._ZNK5thingIjE2idEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv,comdat
```

This one puts the function definition in a linkage section of its own called 
`.text._ZNK5thingIjE2idEv` that will be output, if it's needed, merged into the 
`.text` (i.e. code) section of program in which the object file is linked. A 
linkage section like that, i.e. `.text.<function_name>` is called a *function-section*.
It's a code section that contains *only* the definition of function `<function_name>`.

The directive:

```
.weak   _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
```

is crucial. It classifies `thing<unsigned int>::id() const` as a [weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) symbol.
The GNU linker recognises *strong* symbols and *weak* symbols. For a strong symbol, the
linker will accept only one definition in the linkage. If there are more, it will give a multiple
-definition error. But for a weak symbol, it will tolerate any number of definitions,
and pick one. If a weakly defined symbol also has (just one) strong definition in the linkage then the
strong definition will be picked. If a symbol has multiple weak definitions and no strong definition,
then the linker can pick *any one* of the weak definitions, arbitrarily.

The directive:

```
.type   _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv, @function
```

classifies `thing<unsigned int>::id()` as referring to a *function* - not data.

Then in the body of the definition, the code is assembled at the address
labelled by the weak global symbol `_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv`, the same one locally
labelled `.LFB2`. The code returns 3840 ( = 0xf00).

Next we'll compile `boo.cpp` the same way:

```
g++ -c -save-temps boo.cpp
```

and look again at how `thing<unsigned int>::id()` is defined in `boo.s`

```
    .section    .text._ZNK5thingIjE2idEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
    .type   _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv, @function
_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $2816, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

It's identical, except for our cheat: this definition returns 2816 ( = 0xb00).

While we're here, let's note something that might or might not go without saying:
Once we're in assembly (or object code), *classes have evaporated*. Here,
we're down to: -

- data
- code
- symbols, which can label data or label code.

So nothing here specifically represents *the instantiation of* `thing<T>` *for*
`T = unsigned`. All that's left of `thing<unsigned>` in this instance is
the definition of `_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv` a.k.a `thing<unsigned int>::id() const`.

So now we know what the *compiler* does about instantiating `thing<unsigned>`
in a given translation unit. If it is obliged to instantiate a `thing<unsigned>`
member function, then it assembles the definition of the instantiated member
function at a weakly global symbol that identifies the member function, and it
puts this definition into its own function-section.

Now let's see what the linker does.

First we'll compile the main source file.

```
g++ -c main.cpp
```

Then link all the object files, requesting a diagnostic trace on `_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv`,
and a linkage map file:

```
g++ -o prog main.o foo.o boo.o -Wl,--trace-symbol='_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv',-M=prog.map
foo.o: definition of _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
boo.o: reference to _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
```

So the linker tells us that the program gets the definition of `_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv` from
`foo.o` and *calls* it in `boo.o`.

Running the program shows it's telling the truth:

```
./prog

f00
f00
```

Both `foo()` and `boo()` are returning the value of `thing<unsigned>().id()` 
*as instantiated in* `foo.cpp`.

What has become of the *other* definition of `thing<unsigned int>::id() const`
in `boo.o`? The map file shows us:

**prog.map**

```
...
Discarded input sections
 ...
 ...
 .text._ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
                0x0000000000000000        0xf boo.o
 ...
 ...
```

The linker chucked away the function-section in `boo.o` that
contained the other definition.

Let's now link `prog` again, but this time with `foo.o` and `boo.o` in the
reverse order:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o boo.o foo.o -Wl,--trace-symbol='_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv',-M=prog.map
boo.o: definition of _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
foo.o: reference to _ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
```

This time, the program gets the definition of `_ZNK5thingIjE2idEv` from `boo.o` and
calls it in `foo.o`. The program confirms that:

```
$ ./prog

b00
b00
```

And the map file shows:

```
...
Discarded input sections
 ...
 ...
 .text._ZNK5thingIjE2idEv
                0x0000000000000000        0xf foo.o
 ...
 ...
```

that the linker chucked away the function-section `.text._ZNK5thingIjE2idEv`
from `foo.o`.

That completes the picture.

The compiler emits, in each translation unit, a weak definition of
each instantiated template member in its own function section. The linker
then just picks the *first* of those weak definitions that it encounters
in the linkage sequence when it needs to resolve a reference to the weak
symbol. Because each of the weak symbols addresses a definition, any
one one of them - in particular, the first one - can be used to resolve all references
to the symbol in the linkage, and the rest of the weak definitions are
expendable. The surplus weak definitions must be ignored, because
the linker can only link one definition of a given symbol. And the surplus
weak definitions can be *discarded* by the linker, with no collateral
damage to the program, because the compiler placed each one in a linkage section all by itself.

By picking the *first* weak definition it sees, the linker is effectively
picking at random, because the order in which object files are linked is arbitrary.
But this is fine, *as long as we obey the ODR accross multiple translation units*,
because it we do, then all of the weak definitions are indeed identical. The usual practice of `#include`-ing a class template everywhere from a header file (and not macro-injecting any local edits when we do so) is a fairly robust way of obeying the rule.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: There are far less informative answers on Stack Overflow with far more upvotes. I did what I could, but it's not enough.

Comment: Is it possible to have a template specialization a strong symbol?

Comment: Great answer! Besides an immediate answer, I also learned some tricks about using g++ from this post.

Comment: Presumably this means for non-template functions the compiler emits strong definitions?

Answer (score 6):

Different implementations use different strategies for this.

The GNU compiler, for example, marks template instantiations as [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol). Then at link time, the linker can throw away all definitions but one of the same weak symbol.

The Sun Solaris compiler, on the other hand, does not instantiate templates at all during normal compilation. Then at link time, the linker collects all template instantiations needed to complete the program, and then goes ahead and calls the compiler in a special template-instantiation mode. Thus exactly one instantiation is produced for each template. There are no duplicates to merge or get rid of.

Each approach has its own advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a non-template class definition, for example, `class Bar {...};`, and this class is defined in the header, that is included in multiple translation units. After compilation phase you have two object files with two definitions, right? Do you think linker will create two binary definitions for the class in your final binary? Of course, you have two definitions in two translation units and one final definition in the final binary after the linkage phase is done. This is called linkage collapsing, it is not forced by the standard, the standard only enforces [the ODR rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition), that does not say how the linker resolves the final problem, it is up to the linker, but the only way I have ever seen is the collapsing way of resolution. Of course the linker can keep both definitions, but I cannot image why, since the standard enforces those definitions to be identical in their semantics (see the ODR rule link above for more details), and if those are not the program is ill-formed. Now imaging it was not `Bar` it was `std::vector<int>`. Templates is just a way of code generation in this case, everything else is the same.