# How to understand "most modern linkers will remove redundant code like template instantiations."

Tags: c++, templates, linker, instantiation

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322911/what-do-linkers-do#comment3445435_3323000):

> Great answer. Additionally **most modern linkers will remove redundant code like template instantiations**.

- What does **redundant template instantiations** here mean?
- Aside of template instantiations, what else codes will be redundant when `link-time`?

---

<sub>I will try to answer the first question on my own, if anywhere is wrong, please correct me. BTW, please forgive my poor English :-)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

> - What does **redundant template instantiations** here mean?

---

Assume we have a `template <typename T> class A {};` which is declared in the `a.hpp`. We have two ways to instantiate an object in the `a.cpp`:

#### 1. explicit instantiation

- **Explicit instantiation definition:** `template class A <type>;`
- **Explicit instantiation declaration:** `extern template class A <type>;`

#### 2. implicit instantiation

- > When code refers to a template in context that requires a completely defined type, or when the completeness of the type affects the code, and this particular type **has not been explicitly instantiated**, **implicit instantiation occurs**

When the TUs cannot find the explicit instantiation definition or declaration, t`A<int> a;` will invoke implicit instantiation.

<sub>[difference between specialization and instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates#)</sub>

---

Let's return the Question: **What does redundant template instantiations here mean?**

I will divide it into several cases within one `a.cpp`:

#### Case 1 ---- implicit instantiation

```
#include "a.h"
A<int> a;
```

=>

```
class A<int>
{

};

A<int> a;
```

#### Case 2    ----    implicit instantiation

```
#include "a..h"
A<int> a;
A<int> b;
```

=>

```
class A<int> 
{

};

A<int> a;
A<int> b;
```

#### Case 3 ---- Explicit instantiation definition:

```
#include "a.h"
template class A<int>;
A<int> a;
```

=>

```
#include "a.h"
template class A<int>;
A<int> a;
```

- <sub>Explicit instantiation declaration in the head file will behavior like Case3 ---- no redundant template instantiated.</sub>
- <sub>member function have other rulers, take a look: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template</sub>

---

Conclusion:

- **Implicit instantiation** will produce redundant template instantiations while **explicit instantiation definition/declaration** won't.
- Linker will remove such redundant template instantiations, but it will increase `link-time`.

<sub>If you wonder how does the linker work to remove redundant template instantiations, please read this thread: [How does the linker handle identical template instantiations across translation units?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335046/how-does-the-linker-handle-identical-template-instantiations-across-translation)</sub>

Comment: No, you cannot explicitly instantiate the same template specialization in multiple translation units. [temp.spec]/5: "For a given template and a given set of _template-arguments_, an explicit instantiation definition shall appear at most once in a program."

Comment: There are more issues with this answer. For instance, it presumes that header files are not part of translation units (most clearly seen in point 2, where there's a bold **or**). This erroneous assumption leads to multiple logical problems further on, such as misinterpreting the One Definition Rule.

Comment: @aschepler http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#5 (5.1): **an explicit instantiation definition** shall appear at most once in a program,
(5.2): an **explicit specialization** shall be defined at most once in a program, as specified in **[basic.def.odr]**, and
I think the wording here is different, *5.1* doesn't emphasize **odr**, *5.2* emphasizes.

Comment: @aschepler Besides, http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12 *There can be more than one definition of ......class template,......in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements.*

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for your correction! I will replace translation unit with source file. More corrections are welcome :-)

Comment: @MSalters  several places about *translation units* fixed

Comment: I also think you're confusing template definitions `template<typename T> class Foo { };` and explicit instantiation definitions `template class Foo<int>`. The ODR specifically applies to the former, so template definitions.

Comment: @MSalters Thanks again! It's my fault. Now it is fixed :)

Comment: @陳力 [temp.spec]/5.1 is an additional requirement similar to but written as independent of the ODR. And what would 5.1 mean, if not that you can't explicitly instantiate the same thing twice, even in different TUs? The template part of the quote is talking about implicit instantiations: multiple TUs may implicitly instantiate a template specialization, or one TU may explicitly instantiate and other TUs may implicitly instantiate.

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, sir. It's my fault. Now it is fixed

Comment: I'm still a bit unhappy with the text as written. There's no special treatment for header files versus source files. That's mixing up the phases of translation. Merging a source file and its header files into a Translation Unit has completed before template compilation starts. Furthermore, implicit instantiation is only suppressed if the explicit instantiation (declaration or definition) precedes the implicit instantiation. These details matter; while it's convention to `#include` header files before anything else it's not mandatory.

Comment: @MSalters Quite agree with you. I also think details are vitally important. The only happy thing today is the **really, really valuable** corrections made by you and aschepler. I'll re-organize the answer tomorrow(11:35 PM now, and I have to go to power/water plant for production practice tomorrow morning)

Comment: @MSalters [practice is over](https://twitter.com/_FirstLoveLife_/status/1006464694230454272). If I understand correctly, I think you suggest me to replace head file/source with TU? I made a few editions. But I think you will still be unsatisfied with the answer. If you are willing to edit my answer(directly or community wiki), I will feel honored(Indeed, this is a bad answer, but I am still unwilling to delete it, because your comments are valuable to me)